# Container "pushed down" in IE7+

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I am putting the finishing touches on http://eidman.krd-design.net/.  When I tested out the site on IE8, the main container is dropping below the navigation sidebar.  Elements of the navigation are also stacking on top of each other.  Has anyone run into these issues before and if so what is the fix?

Thank you for any and all help, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: more than likely you have some malformed html that IE doesn't like, while webkit or gecko browsers (notably chrome, FF, safari) seem to be a little better at filling in the blanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your markup using http://validator.w3.org/check you have a TON of errors such as stray `</li>` and `</div>` tags, white space between in a `h ref` and duplicate closing anchor tags `</a></a>`